# Create individual names for multiple sockets in python in order to save data received to different files

Tags: python, sockets

I currently have created a code that creates multiple sockets with different ports. Each port will receive data from the client side and save them to different files for analysis. I would like to name each connection something unique to ensure that the data is saved to the right file. Or is there a way for me to check what port the data is being received on and save it based on the port? The data will come in at the same time so ensuring the data is going to the correct file is critical. All the clients are coming from the localhost so checking address won't be helpful.

I have tried to find a way to check for which port the data is coming from but I can't figure that out. I can't just check which port is currently connected as all the ports in the list will be connected at once. I'm using python 3.10.9.

Kind Regards

```
import select
import socket
import root_directory
from Account import Symbols

s = Symbols.Symbols()
symbol_total = len(s.Symbol())
ports_list=[*range(9000, (symbol_total + 9000), 1)]

def make_socket(number):
  sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
  sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
  sock.bind(('', number))
  sock.listen(5)
  return sock

read_list= list(map(lambda x: make_socket(x), ports_list))

notAccepted = read_list[:]

while True:
    readable, writable, errored = select.select(read_list, [], [])
    for s in readable:
        if s in notAccepted:
            client_socket, address = s.accept()
            read_list.append(client_socket)
        else:
            data = client_socket.recv(1000000)
            cummdata = ''
            cummdata = data.decode("utf-8")
            print(s)
            if data:
                pass
            else:
                s.close()
                read_list.remove(s)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`socket.getpeername()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.socket.getpeername) retrieves the address/port of the remote end of the socket.

[`socket.getsockname()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.socket.getsockname) retrieves the address/port of the local end of the socket.

Also, [`socket.makefile()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.socket.makefile) wraps a socket in a file-like object so your receives are buffered until you have a complete message, such as a complete newline-terminated text message as in my example below.  Note that `.recv(n)` can receive 1-n bytes of data and you can't assume you have a complete message in TCP, which isn't message-based.  It is a streaming protocol.

server.py

```py
import select
import socket

BASE = 9000
SOCKS = 5

servers = []
for port in range(BASE, BASE+SOCKS):
    sock = socket.socket()
    sock.bind(('', port))
    sock.listen()
    servers.append(sock)

read_list = {s:None for s in servers}

while True:
    readable, writable, errored = select.select(read_list, [], [])
    for s in readable:
        if s in servers:
            client_socket, address = s.accept()
            client = client_socket.makefile('r', encoding='utf8')
            server_port = client_socket.getsockname()[1]
            client_port = address[1]
            # For clients, store the ports and makefile wrapper
            # for later lookup in the dictionary.
            # You could store the "name" of the port or log file here.
            read_list[client_socket] = server_port, client_port, client
            print(f'{client_port}->{server_port}: CONNECTED')
        else:
            server_port, client_port, client = read_list[s]
            data = client.readline()
            if data:
                print(f'{client_port}->{server_port}: {data}', end='')
            else:
                print(f'{client_port}->{server_port}: DISCONNECTED')
                del read_list[s]
                s.close()
                client.close()
```

client.py

```py
import socket

SOCKS = 5
BASE = 9000

socks = [socket.socket() for _ in range(SOCKS)]
for port, s in enumerate(socks, BASE):
    s.connect(('localhost', port))
for s in socks:
    for i in range(1,3):
        s.sendall(f'message {i} on port {s.getsockname()[1]} to port {s.getpeername()[1]}\n'.encode())
for s in socks:
    s.close()
```

Server output:

```
30107->9000: CONNECTED
30108->9001: CONNECTED
30109->9002: CONNECTED
30110->9003: CONNECTED
30111->9004: CONNECTED
30107->9000: message 1 on port 30107 to port 9000
30108->9001: message 1 on port 30108 to port 9001
30109->9002: message 1 on port 30109 to port 9002
30110->9003: message 1 on port 30110 to port 9003
30111->9004: message 1 on port 30111 to port 9004
30107->9000: message 2 on port 30107 to port 9000
30108->9001: message 2 on port 30108 to port 9001
30109->9002: message 2 on port 30109 to port 9002
30110->9003: message 2 on port 30110 to port 9003
30111->9004: message 2 on port 30111 to port 9004
30107->9000: DISCONNECTED
30108->9001: DISCONNECTED
30109->9002: DISCONNECTED
30110->9003: DISCONNECTED
30111->9004: DISCONNECTED
```